# Domain lock on Magento extensions

Tags: php, html, ioncube

How can i put a domain lock on my Magento extension?

I made a Magento extension and i want it to run on some specific domains and also i want encode it with Ioncube.
how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As practice shows, better don't do that.

Disadvantages of decoding:

- if someone wants to get your module - he will get it, even if its
  decoded. It's just a matter of time.
- if magento shop owner will have some problems on hist host
  with your module - he will contact to you every time.
- In some cases the person who want to install on his host your module (when you allow it) - in some cases he will need to install additional libraries.